# How do I use boost::icl::hull?

Tags: c++, boost

The following code doesn't work:

```
typedef boost::icl::interval_set<unsigned> bi_list_type;
typedef bi_list_type::value_type iv_type;
std::vector<iv_type> y;
iv_type x; // how to initialize this?

for (auto i : y)
{
  x = boost::icl::hull(x, i);
}
```

The problem is, that `x` is default constructed and thus in the end 0 is always the lower bound of x. Is there any better way to use `boost::icl::hull`? And if so, how could I know without asking here (the doc isn't helpful in this regard)?

(The `std::vector` is only an example, the interval creation happens actually inside the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"a better way to use boost::icl::hull"*

That depends 100% on the desired goal.

> *"(the doc isn't helpful in this regard)"*

The doc also doesn't know your goal; it only tells you operations you can use to reach the goal.

I don't know your goal, but to me it looks very much like it's working:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1138d55210e22cfc)**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace icl = boost::icl;

int main() {
    using iv_type = icl::discrete_interval<unsigned int, std::less>;

    iv_type h{};

    for (auto& i : {
        iv_type::open(0, 0),
        iv_type::left_open(5, 8),
        iv_type::right_open(4, 6),
        iv_type::closed(6, 7),
    }) {
        std::cout << "h: " << h << " adding " << i << "\n";
        h = hull(h, i);
    }
    std::cout << "h: " << h << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
h: [) adding ()
h: [) adding (5,8]
h: (5,8] adding [4,6)
h: [4,8] adding [6,7]
h: [4,8]
```

### Alternatives

Since you mentioned interval_set perhaps you can do better:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0786565d377c20aa)**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace icl = boost::icl;

int main() {
    using set  = icl::interval_set<unsigned int>;
    using ival = set::value_type;
    auto s     = set{};

    s.add(ival::open(0, 0));
    s.add(ival::left_open(5, 8));
    s.add(ival::right_open(4, 6));
    s.add(ival::closed(6, 7));

    std::cout << "hull: " << hull(s) << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
hull: [4,8]
```

Due to the orderedness of the set this does something different, I think. Which may or may not be what you want depending on the meaning/goal.

### Another Alternative

If you really want the "left-fold" behaviour in sequence, but can't have an initializer like `[)` or `[min(), max())` then perhaps write it as a left-fold:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af68986122755d5c)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
namespace icl = boost::icl;

int main() {
    using iv_type = icl::discrete_interval<unsigned int, std::less>;
    std::vector v{
        iv_type::open(0, 0),
        iv_type::left_open(5, 8),
        iv_type::right_open(4, 6),
        iv_type::closed(6, 7),
    };

    if (v.size()>0) {
        std::cout
          << "h: "
          << std::accumulate(begin(v) + 1, end(v), v.front(),
                [](auto a, auto const& b) {
                    return icl::hull(std::move(a), b);
                })
          << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which for our simple data still prints

```
h: [4,8]
```